# Users with dual roles - can it be done with one user account?

Tags: administration, security

I'm trying to figure out how to set up security for a person that has a dual role that entails two separate hierarchical structures.  Hi primary role is to work with the advancement group, which gives him access to alumni, staff and other donors to the college.  His second role is as a athletic coach, where he needs access to potential students and all of their athletic recruiting information.  When we set up the security, we intentionally set it up so the advancement group would not see the same information as the admissions (recruiting) group.  I know I can manage object access through permission sets, but I believe my issues are with page layout and reporting.  Do I need to move this person above the branch of the hierarchy to get him the reporting access that he needs?  Any suggestions on how to handle the page layout issue?

Any help or advise would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sharing considerations - if you'll disable "Grant access using hierarchies" on athletic-related data and use sharing rules to provide this guy's / girl's access - should be fine. Meaning that anybody above him in the advancement-related roles shouldn't get the access just by fact of being above him/her.

If roles don't work for you you can even go extreme and take him out of the role hierarchy, deal exclusively via sharing rules (they'd have to be criteria-based I think because "Owner in role X" won't match).

As for page layouts - I don't follow you. Page layout assignment is Profile-related, nothing to do with Roles.

Reporting - from what I remember Roles (& Territories) appear as magical hierarchy setting only on Accounts and Opportunities. You should be OK if you're using custom objects. There might be some issues with "My Team's [objects]" though - depends if you use that filter in reports & list views, I don't see it used too often.